# What uncountable ordinals live in the long line?

Tags: general-topology, ordinals, well-orders

It is a relatively simple exercise to prove that a well-ordered set is order-isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R$ (under the usual ordering) if and only if it is countable. You can say that $\mathbb R$ is "too small" to contain any uncountable well-ordered sets.

So my question is, can you embed bigger well-ordered sets in the long line? For those who don't know, the long line can be constructed by taking the minimal uncountable well-ordered set (i.e. $\omega_1$) and taking its Cartesian product with $[0,1)$ under the dictionary order. So obviously $\omega_1$ itself is emebeddable in the long line, just by taking the left endpoints of all the intervals $[0,1)$. But can you embed bigger uncountable ordinals, and if so how big? I'm guessing that you may be able to embed all well-ordered sets with cardinality less than or equal to $\aleph_1$, the cardinality of the set of countable ordinals.

Comment: You should look into surreal numbers. They have a similar relationship to ordinals as the reals do to the natural numbers (except the surreals are not topologically complete, nor do they have any topologically complete field extension).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not that many, really.

The thing about the "long line" is that every proper initial segment is "just a line" (read: an interval of $\Bbb R$). So every proper initial segment can only house countable ordinals.

So no uncountable ordinal greater than $\omega_1$ can be embedded in the long line; and since the long line trivially embeds $\omega_1$, by picking the end-points of the intervals, we get that the only uncountable ordinal that can be embedded in the long line is $\omega_1$ itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What about bigger versions of the long line, i.e. versions that are constructed using a Cartesian product with a bigger uncountable ordinal?  Do you ever get more ordinals than you put in, i.e. can you embed larger ordinals than the ordinal you use for the Cartesian product?

Comment: I  don't have time or inclination to verify the details. Off the bat, I would say that the supremum of the ordinals that embed into $[0,1)\times\alpha$ is $\alpha\cdot\omega_1$, and that supremum is not necessarily a maximum. (Note that $\alpha\cdot\beta$ is the order type of $\beta\times\alpha$.)